# Encode Audio/Video FIles placed in Sdcard and then Decode the same and play it in Android

Tags: android, media-player, media, encoder, decoder

I need to encode the audio/video files that are placed in sdcard.
    Then later on I have an User-Interface, where there is a media player where in I play these encoded files after decoding them.
      Reason I need to encode these files is because, I dont want these files to be played by Android's default Media Player and want them to be played by my own App's Media Player.
      Could you please suggest me some audio/video encoders and decoders supported by android.

Thank you